# Java ObjectInputStream not being instantiated

Tags: java, exception, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am creating a kind of messenger program, where clients communicate with the server etc.
The problem I have stumbled upon is when trying to create the ObjectInputStream and the ObjectOutputStream. Here is the method that instantiated the object streams:

```
private void initializeStreams() {
        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            if (input != null) {
                System.out.println("ObjectInputStream successfully initiated");
            } else {
                System.out.println("ObjectInputStream is null but did not return an exception when being instantiated");
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Could not initialize ObjectInputStream: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            if (output != null) {
                System.out.println("ObjectOutputStream successfully initiated");
            } else {
                System.out.println("ObjectOutputStream is null but did not return an exception when being instantiated");
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Could not initialize ObjectOutputStream: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }`
```

The problem within this method is that NONE of the System.out.println() methods are getting called, even though, at least to my knowledge, one for each of the streams should be getting called. For example, when instantiating the ObjectInputStream, it should either throw an Exception (which it apparently does not because the System.out.println() is not getting called), returning null (which also does not seem to be the case because the System.out.println() is not getting called) or successfully create the ObjectInputStream object, which it does not because the System.out.println() is not getting called. Why does it not run into any of these situations? Am I missing another situation that might occur?

P.S. Yes, the initializeStreams() method is being called from the program, I just checked it putting a System.out.println() at the very first line of the method.

Thank you

Comment: Add breakpoints and debug.

Comment: Try debugging your code, see what happens when you step through that method one line at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I managed to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to write something on the console in the finally-cluster.
What possibly could be is that an exception is thrown, which doesn't get catched.

But you would see that...wouldn't you.

My first tip: Debug your program, that's what often helped me.

But you could also try this:

```
private void initializeStreams() {
        input = null;
        output = null;
        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Could not initialize ObjectInputStream: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }

        //just copied the if outside of the try-catch-cluster
        if (input != null) {
                    System.out.println("ObjectInputStream successfully initiated");
        } else {
          System.out.println("ObjectInputStream is null but did not return an exception when being instantiated");


        try {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Could not initialize ObjectOutputStream: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }

        if (output != null) {
            System.out.println("ObjectOutputStream successfully initiated");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ObjectOutputStream is null but did not return an exception when being instantiated");
                }
    }`
```

Thats one thing I would try in order to find out what or where the problem is.
Even if it doesn't make that much sense ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, I was able to fix the issue eventually. I explained how in another comment, you can go and check it out if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

Well, you catch only `IOException`. There might be `RuntimeException` for instance in your code. You won't get to your catch block in this case.

Change `IOException` to `Exception` and you will see the reason.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I eventually fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

`new ObjectInputStream()` can throw exceptions other than IOException, but your try-catch only captures IOException. What happens if the exception thrown is one of the other types?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I was eventually able to fix the issue, it was related to the program getting stuck while calling socket.getInputStream() because a weird issue was occurring on my server and it was not able to instantiate its output stream, therefore the socket.getInputStream() method was blocking the program because it could not find the output stream from the other side

Answer (score 0):

Replace `IOException` with the `Exception` class which is the parent of all exception classes.Whatever may be the exception,it will surely get caught using `Exception` class in catch block.

So replace `catch (IOException ioe)` this with `catch (Exception ioe)` everywhere in your code.Then u may find where is the exception coming from.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I was eventually able to fix the issue. If you are interested I wrote how in another comment